# parseInt Array returns undefined - javascript

Tags: javascript, foreach, parseint

Initially I had,

```
var value = parseInt(getValue(), 10);
```

where `getValue()` returned one value but now it returns multiple values.

I tried this:

```
var value = [];

    getValue().forEach(function(item) {
       value.push(parseInt(item, 10))
    });
```

But it returns undefined.

Arrow functions are not supported.

Comment: Maybe we need to see what getValue actually holds since the code looks correct.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the problem. Isn't `value` just holding the array you need after your code ends? Is simply `return value` what you are missing? Otherwise it seems that the problem lies inside `getValue()` function.

Comment: It is resolved now. This code was for live tests and it was not hitting domain to fetch the values and hence getValue() was not returning anything. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`getValue` is a function. You have to *call* the function to get the return value:

```
let values = getValue().map(e => parseInt(e, 10));
```

If you have to stick with ES5, try this:

```
var values = getValue().map(function(item){
    return parseInt(item, 10);
});
```

Comment: I called the function, there was typo in my post, which I edited.